# Windows vscode python extension install autopep8 failed: can't open file problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
Admin@PS2020LDRRNIBW MINGW64 ~
$ C:/Python38/python.exe c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.109390\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U autopep8 --user
C:\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'c:UsersAdmin.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2020.8.109390pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: Please forumulate a proper question and add a description what you exactly did to get this error. Otherwise nobody can help you and your question gets closed.